# Как осуществлять переход между страницами в рамках MVVM в Xamarin?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Я знаю про `Page.Navigation`, но чтобы его задействовать нужно прописать обработчики событий на кнопки и уже в них "переходить" на новую страницу.

В рамках MVVM так и делается или же можно перенести "логику перехода" между страницами во ViewModel?

Comment: Вам нужно написать сервис навигации по типу [такого](https://github.com/bulsond/calorizator228/blob/master/Calorizator/Calorizator/NavigationService.cs). Или повторить навигацию как это сделано в шаблоне нового проекта типа `Shell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал [Bulson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222542/bulson), можно написать [такой](https://github.com/bulsond/calorizator228/blob/master/Calorizator/Calorizator/NavigationService.cs) сервис. Именно так я и реализую